# Why does playing of SoundEffectInstance take more time at first time?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, audio, xna

I'm precreatring `SoundEffectInstance` for each `SoundEffect` but it still have some time to loading when some sound playing first time. Is it some kind of lazy loading? Now I wrote `sound.Play(0, 0, 0);` for each `SoundEffect` at loading time. It's take some time at loading, but there is no more waiting when `SoundEffectInstance` play first time. I didn't like this way. So is there some more elegant solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The first time the sound is played it is loaded into memory, which will take time.

You could try and hide this behaviour by trying to play the track before it's needed and then pausing it immediately so it's in memory when you do need it.

Additionaly, you could try different compressions and formats of audio as that can affect load time too.

Comment: I tried to played before but with
    `var tmp = sound.CreateInstance();`
    `tmp.Volume = 1;`
    `tmp.Play();`
    `tmp.Stop();`
but it don't actualy have effect